# What are steps to separating wp_posts table?

Tags: url, search, woocommerce

Is it possible to keep my products data separated from wp_posts?
Are there any working solutions, or guides to follow? How to keep my products data organized. The main problem is that I can't directly import my records from CSV. I didn't found WP plugin to fit my needs.

Comment: I think, that in this way, is not possible, products are a custom post type in wordpress as orders too. Be more explicit in your question regarding why you need this? You want to import records in WooCommerce / or export to import them somewhere else? Please update your question, It's very unclear…

Comment: I have fixed datastructure. I need this to import SQL records to WooCommerce, and update them every week. I thought the best idea is to keep a CSV file for new, existing products.  For testing purposes I think it would be nice to just DROP TABLE 'products'  and CREATE TABLE 'producs'. I know that this way isn't right, but I want to understand how that works using this way.